# Running code only after successful uninstallation in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to handle event when user clicks NO in uninstallation confirmation prompt?

[image]

And if NO is clicked, don't execute DeinitializeUninstall() ?

Or is it possible to handle NO button from DeinitializeUninstall() function?

Basically, I wont to avoid `DelTree` here:

```pascal
procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
  { if we are running in /SILENT mode, then this is an overinstall - }
  { don't delete additional folder}
  if not UninstallSilent() then
  begin
    DelTree(ExpandConstant('{#BSPLOC}'),True, True, True);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your logic is wrong. It looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).

I do not think, that you want to detect "No". I believe, you want to run the code during or after uninstallation.

So use an event function that matches your requirements. The function is [`CurUninstallStepChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged). And depending on when you exactly need the code to run, check for a corresponding value of `CurUninstallStep` argument (`usUninstall`, `usPostUninstall` or `usDone`).

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usDone then
  begin
    // ...
  end;
end;
```

For similar questions, see:

- [Inno Setup: Conditionally delete non-empty directory in user's home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28866716/850848)
- [How to save a folder when user confirms uninstallation? (Inno Setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42684469/850848)

---

*Ntb, it also seems that you abuse the `/SILENT` switch to detect if the uninstaller is run automatically as part of some process (upgrade?). What if the user runs the uninstaller silently him/herself? You should add another custom switch to signal the automatic run. But that's another question.*